# Copy + Paste funcionality doesn't work between host and virtual machine both VirtualBox and VMWare

Tags: virtualbox, clipboard, virtual, vmware, copy-paste

Good morning,
I cannot copy&paste between host and virtual machine. It seems that both host and VM won't share Clipboard.

I tried many programs and different virtual machines and it doesn't work at all in both directions.
I can't copy anything.

Host is Windows 10. I tried:
VMWare Workstation 12, VMWare Workstation 15 - Fedora (Gnome, lxqt, lxed)
VirtualBox - Fedora (lxqt), Solaris, Windows 8.1

All options inside VirtualBox either VMWare were set properly.

On any of listed machines copy&paste doesn't work.

Comment: Have you already seen the requirements and restrictions for that action in Workstation? https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/15.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-1109A03F-3BD3-4292-AEF6-D943445519B5.html

Comment: Hello, yes, all requirements are met